# React js multiple instances of date picker

Tags: javascript, reactjs, datepicker, react-datepicker

I am having problem updating the date on react-datepicker if I use multiple instances of datepicker.

Date picker Component:

```
<DatePicker
  selected={this.state.from}
  onChange={this.changeDate.bind(this)}
/>
```

On change handler:

```
changeDate(date) {
    this.setState({
        from : date
    });
}
```

This seems to work fine if i am using only one instance, but when I add more than one instances, I have to create separate onchange handler for each of the newly created date picker component.
What I am looking for is a way to write just a single onchange handler function and handle change events for multiple instances of datepicker in that same function.

Comment: It sounds like you have one view containing multiple DatePickers, and each updates its own separate state property, right? If so, you can rewrite `changeDate` to accept an argument indicating the state property name, and return a function that calls `setState` on that property only.

Comment: Yeah that is correct, and i tried doing that but i am not able to update the state inside the handlechange function, if i update the state with string literal like `"startDate": dateValue`, then it works but if i use the function parameter like `dateName: dateValue` then it doesnt work, even though `dateName=startDate`

Comment: Are you using react-datepicker? I'm having the same issue you have. How did you manage to solve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can have a object `field` state to store each date value in property

```
this.state = {
    fields: {}
}

handleDateChange = (dateName, dateValue) => {
    this.setState({
        fields: {
            ...this.fields,
            [dateName]: dateValue
        }
    })
}

// IN RENDER
<ReactDatepicker 
    value={this.fields["dateStart"]}
    onChange={(value) => handleDateChange("dateStart", value)}
/>
```

Comment: Everything seems to work except this part

`fields: {
            ...this.fields,
            [dateName]: dateValue
        }`


i tried this

`fields: {
        [dateName]: dateValue
      }`


and this


`fields: {
        dateName: dateValue
      }`

None of them worked, but this works:

`fields: {
        'startDate': dateValue
      }`

Comment: Can you put your code to codesanbox or somewhere ? Just say with a line of code not helping much

Comment: You can read more [here](https://reactjs.org/docs/forms.html#handling-multiple-inputs)

Comment: I got it working, I had some newbie errors in the code, thanks @dungtranhcmus

Answer (score 3):

You can have `onChange` Handler like that with two argument `dateName` and `dateValue`

```
//in state
 this.state = {
  startDate: moment(),
  endDate: moment(),
}

//My onChange handler function    
handleDateChange(dateName, dateValue) {
    let { startDate, endDate } = this.state;
    if (dateName === 'startDateTime') {
      startDate = dateValue;
    } else {
      endDate = dateValue;
    }
    this.setState({
      startDate,
      endDate,
    });
  }

// Date Picker component
<DatePicker
    id="start-date-time"
    name="startDateTime"
    className="form-control"
    selected={this.state.startDate}
    value={this.state.startDate}
    onChange={date => this.handleDateChange('startDateTime', date)}
    showTimeSelect
    timeFormat="HH:mm"
    timeIntervals={15}
    dateFormat="YYYY-MM-DD, h:mm a"
    timeCaption="time"
  />
//other use of Date picker
<DatePicker


 id="end-date-time"
  name="endDateTime"
  className="form-control"
  selected={this.state.endDate}
  value={this.state.endDate}
  onChange={date => this.handleDateChange('endDateTime', date)}
  placeholderText="choose end date of event"
  isClearable={true}
  showTimeSelect
  timeFormat="HH:mm"
  timeIntervals={15}
  dateFormat="YYYY-MM-DD, h:mm a"
  timeCaption="time"
/>
```