# React.js store multiple datepicker dates against id's in state

Tags: reactjs, date, datepicker, state

I have a problem where I am generating datepickers `on the fly` based on a number of props passed down. The props passed down from the parent component are charges of a particular product. So say there a 6 charges, then we create an input field containing the charge and then for each one a corresponding datepicker needs to be displayed.

The image below hopefully displays this better than i could explain it! (Picture paints a thousand words they say!!)

[image]

So my problem is this, if the user updates all of the dates in the datepickers (to the right) then how do I save each date to the particular id? I would obviously store them in state, but how do i save each one?

I cant just have values in state pre-set as the number of datepickers and charges can be different each time. Sometimes there may be 1, sometimes there may be 10.

The code I have for this component is as follows:

```
export class Charges extends Component {

constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
        currentItem: 0,
        newDate: ''
        fields: []
    }

    this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
}


****** EDIT *********
handleDateChange = (e) => {
    const date = e.target.value;
    const chargeId = e.target.name;
    console.log(date);
    this.setState({
        fields: [
            ...this.state.fields,
            [chargeId]: date
        ]
    }, () => console.log(this.state.fields))
}
**********

render() {
 const {charges, chargeTypes} = this.props;
 if (charges.length === 0) { return null; }

return <Form>
    <h3>Charges</h3>
    {charges.map(charge => {
        console.log(charge);
        const chargeType = chargeTypes.find(type => type.code === charge.type) || {};
        return <Grid>
            <Grid.Row columns={2}>
                <Grid.Column>
                    <Form.Input
                        key={charge.id}
                        label={chargeType.description || charge.type}
                        value={Number(charge.amount).toFixed(2)}
                        readOnly
                        width={6} />
                </Grid.Column>
                <Grid.Column>
                    <DateInput
                        name={charge.id}
                        selected={this.state.newDate}
                        onChange={this.handleChange}
                        value={charge.effectiveDate}
                    />
                </Grid.Column>
            </Grid.Row>
        </Grid>
    })}
    <Divider hidden />
    <br />
</Form>
}
}
```

As you can see, I will just overwrite previous' state value if the user was to update more than one datepicker?

I have viewed the following article, but its not really what i want:
[Multiple DatePickers React](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50867479/react-js-multiple-instances-of-date-picker)

How can i achieve the functionality I want? I hope I have made this clear? If there are any questions please don't hesitate to ask!

*** Edited Answer ***

I have now updated the handleDateChangeMethod to store the data in an array (as this is what I want) however, it only gives me the `chargeId` and not the date mapped to it!

See screenshot below:

[image]

Is there anyway to save like this in the state array [chargeId: date]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set a unique prop in the `state` for each datepicker by its `name` attribute using [computed property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer#Computed_property_names)

```js
handleChange = (e, date) => {
    const value = moment(date);
    const chargeId = e.target.name;
    console.log(chargeId);
    this.setState({[chargeId]: value}, () => console.log(this.state[chargeId]));
}
```

Read more about this approach in React's website: https://reactjs.org/docs/forms.html#handling-multiple-inputs

Comment: Hi @Mosh Feu I have edited the answer. Thanks for the speedy reply!

Comment: Seems like you forgot to wrap the object with `{}`. It should be  `fields: [
            ...this.state.fields,
            {[chargeId]: date}
        ]`